# Jquery how to select elements containing specific value(s) in data attribute array?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

let's say I have the following elements

```
<div data-tags="[8,18,32,52,53,56]"></div>
<div data-tags="[8,2,3]"></div>
<div data-tags="[4,6,10]"></div>
```

Now I want to select elements having "8" in their data-tags attribute, how would I do that with jquery?
I'm trying $('[data-tags~=8]') also $('[data-tags~="8"]') but neither of them work. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I don't think $('[data-tags*=8]') would be a solution since it would also include items with values of 18, 86 804 etc. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var found = $('div[data-tags]').filter(function() {
  return JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-tags")).indexOf(8) > -1
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var found = $('div[data-tags]').filter(function() {
  return JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-tags")).indexOf(8) > -1
})
var found2 = $('div[data-tags]').filter(function() {
  return JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-tags")).indexOf(18) > -1
})
console.log("Found",found.length, "by number 8");
console.log("Found",found2.length, "by number 18");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-tags="[8,18,32,52,53,56]"></div>
<div data-tags="[8,2,3]"></div>
<div data-tags="[4,6,10]"></div>
```

Comment: Alright, looks like this does help me achieve what I want. I'll wait for another hour if no cleaner solution is added (purely just jquery selector), I will mark yours as accepted answer. Thank you

Comment: @Matrix You can use `$('div[data-tags*="8"]')` but this will also get selected by 18,28, so on

Comment: Yes, I figured it would. Thanks again. I applied your solution with some modifications (Just a personal preference) `$('div[data-tags]').filter(function(){return $.inArray(8, $(this).data("tags")) != -1;});`